# Keycloak Verification Error

Tags: keycloak

When I deploy my webapp in Keycloak standalone (user/roles defined), I can log in without a problem, but when I deploy it on Wildfly with Keycloak adapter, I cannot log in, and get the error:

```
[org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator] failed verification of token: 
Token type is incorrect. Expected 'Bearer' but was 'null'
```

Where is the 'Bearer' token defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the the culprit. If somebody else bumps into the same issue: I spent hours of worktime on Keycloak 1.5.0.Final. Yesterday 1.6.0 was released and issue is resolved. The same problem appeared even in the demo examples. So if you are using Wildfly with adapter, stay away from Keycloak 1.5.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps as I haven't encountered your error message. Have a look at this and see, if it gives you a hint. If not, I'm sorry and good luck :)

Open the admin console and go to > clients
This is where you configure your client and also the access type (confidential, public, bearer-only). Maybe a configuration error here?

[image: Screenshot from the admin console]

Comment: As far as I know 'confidential' access is for http (browser access), and bearer only for services like database (so no browser access). Public access is not what I am looking for.
p.s. the examples given in previous versions work fine in keycloak standalone, but if I deploy them on Wildfly with adapter, I get error: *wrong token 'redirect_uri*

Comment: I used the following config steps to get it to work: <WILDFLY_HOME>/bin/standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-keycloak.xml and ../<...>/wildfly-9.0.1/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=configureWildfly.cli change datasource in standalone/configuration/keycloak-server.json and for the adapter package jboss-cli.sh -c --file=adapter-install.cli

Comment: Due to project environment, I am limited to wildfly 8.2.1 and I do not have standalone-keycloak.xml in ...standalone/configuration/. I will test the project on Wildfly 9 just to be sure it is local to WF 8.2.1

Comment: You get the files here: http://keycloak.jboss.org/keycloak/downloads there's also a subfolder on the site called "adapters". I was using: Keycloak-overlay-1.4.0.Final and 
Keycloak Adapter: keycloak-wf9-adapter-dist-1.4.0.Final. Then you unzip them such that the files end up in the according wildfly folders.

Comment: It is working on wildfly 9, but not 8. At least I have a last option. IntelliJ 13 is not compatible with wf 9 and we have IntelliJ 13 license on most computers. Thanks for the tips